# Storing Multiple Parameters in Global Constant

Tags: vba, ms-access, parameters, global-variables, ms-access-2010

I am using an Access 2010 database and I cannot figure out how to store multiple parameters for a function call in a single constant string.

For example, let's say I want to open a form with the following:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "someformname",acNormal,,"ID=50",acFormEdit, acWindowNormal,"OPENARGS"
```

Can I store all that in a global constant such as

```
Public Const C_FORMOPENEDIT as String
```

and then open the form like this?

```
DoCmd.OpenForm C_FORMOPENEDIT
```

It does not seem to work in this way. How can I get VBA to recognize that this is a series of parameters separated by commas? Or is this not possible?

Note: I have attempted already to call it by the parameter name such as `FormName :=` and I have also already verified that any quotes in the string, where needed, are passed through. (like """)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do isn't possible. Your constant will be evaluated as if it is the name of the form. Since it is constant and not dynamic, I'd suggest to create separate procedures, such as

```vbs
Public Sub FormOpenEdit(sFormName As String)

    DoCmd.OpenForm sFormName, acNormal, , "ID=50", acFormEdit, acWindowNormal, "OPENARGS"

End Sub

Public Sub FormOpenAdd(sFormName As String)

    DoCmd.OpenForm sFormName, acNormal, , "ID=50", acFormAdd, acWindowNormal, "OPENARGS"

End Sub
```

Alternatively you could build a Enum to select the mode, so you can use just one sub

Comment: Thank you. That is what I thought was the case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below. I use it for opening forms right from ribbon menu – xml can store strings only. String with arguments should be slightly modified, as described in comments. 
If you use DoCmd.OpenForm with default parameters and form default view is Datasheet, it opens as single form anyway. The function also includes a piece of code, which corrects this problem.

```
' non-constant arguments should be able to evaluated by Eval function
' Replace quotes (") by "{" and "}"
' Example of arguments:
'   "acNormal, , {[CODE]='DO022666'}, acFormEdit, GetEditFormWindowMode()"

Public Sub MyOpenForm(strFrm As String, strFrmArgs As String)
    Dim frm As Form
    Dim iDefView As Integer
    Dim astrArgs() As String
    Dim avArgs(6) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim arg As Variant
    Dim bArg0Defined As Boolean


    'default args
    avArgs(0) = acNormal
    avArgs(3) = acFormEdit
    avArgs(4) = acWindowNormal

    astrArgs = Split(strFrmArgs, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(astrArgs)
        If i > 5 Then Exit For
        arg = EvalFormArgument(astrArgs(i))
        If Not IsNull(arg) Then
            avArgs(i) = arg
        End If
    Next i

    'If View argument ommited, check for DefaultView=Datasheet form property and open form in Datasheet view
    bArg0Defined = False
    If UBound(astrArgs) > 0 Then
        If Len(Trim(astrArgs(0))) > 0 Then
            bArg0Defined = True
        End If
    End If
    If Not bArg0Defined Then
        'Determine form properties
        DoCmd.OpenForm strFrm, acDesign, , , , acHidden
        Set frm = Forms(strFrm)
        iDefView = frm.DefaultView
        DoCmd.Close acForm, strFrm
        Set frm = Nothing

        If iDefView = 2 Then 'Datasheet view
            avArgs(0) = acFormDS
        End If
    End If

    DoCmd.OpenForm strFrm, avArgs(0), avArgs(1), avArgs(2), avArgs(3), avArgs(4), avArgs(5)

End Sub

Public Function EvalFormArgument(A As String) As Variant
Dim ret As Variant


A = Trim(A)

If A = "" Then
    EvalFormArgument = Null
    Exit Function
End If
Select Case A
    Case "acNormal": ret = 0
    Case "acDesign": ret = 1
    Case "acFormDS": ret = 3
    Case "acFormPivotChart": ret = 5
    Case "acFormPivotTable": ret = 4
    Case "acLayout": ret = 6
    Case "acPreview": ret = 2
    Case "acFormAdd": ret = 0
    Case "acFormEdit": ret = 1
    Case "acFormPropertySettings": ret = -1
    Case "acFormReadOnly": ret = 2
    Case "acDialog": ret = 3
    Case "acHidden": ret = 1
    Case "acIcon": ret = 2
    Case "acWindowNormal": ret = 0
    Case Else
        A = Replace(A, "{", """")
        A = Replace(A, "}", """")
        ret = Eval(A)
End Select
EvalFormArgument = ret

End Function
```